# What is the dimension of a vector-valued function space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

For example, if we have a vector-valued function space

$$
S = [V^{k+1,k}, V^{k,k+1}]^T
$$
where the component space in two coordinates is
$$
V^{m,n} := \{v: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} \mid v = \sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^n c_{i,j} x_1^i x_2^j,~~ x_1 \in \mathbb{R}, x_2 \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$

1. What is the dimension of $V^{m,n}$? I think there are $(m+1)(n+1)-1$ basis functions spanned the space, **where the constant $c_{0,0} x_1^0 x_2^0$ should be excluded**, so $\operatorname{dim}(V^{m,n}) = (m+1)(n+1)-1$. Is that correct?
2. What is the dimension of $S$? **Shall we add up the dimension of each component space, or take square?** If my answer to Q1 is correct, should the $\operatorname{dim}(S)$ be $2((k+2)(k+1)-1)$ or $((k+2)(k+1)-1)^2$?

Comment: What does the notation $S = [V^{k+1,k}, V^{k,k+1}]^T$ mean?

Comment: Is $S$ intended to be the set of "column vectors" with first entry in $V^{k+1, k}$ and second entry in $V^{k,k+1}$?  If so, that is an example of a vector space "direct sum."  Think about how you might construct a basis for that space from bases for the 'entry' vector spaces. (This is often how one computes dimensions of spaces made out of other spaces: you prove a theorem about how to obtain a basis for the new space from bases of the constituent spaces.)

Comment: @JesseMadnick It means $S$ is a vector-valued space with two components in $V^{k+1,k}$ and $V^{k,k+1}$.

Comment: @leslietownes Yes, you are right. I think the answers I proposed are correct. Please point out the mistake if they are not.

Comment: It helps to think in terms of bases and not dimensions alone. Dimensions are the sizes of bases. I don't see a reason to exclude constant polynomials from the definition of $V^{m,n}$ unless that is an additional unstated hypothesis.  The set $\{x_1^i x_2^j: 0 \leq i \leq m, 0 \leq j \leq n\}$ is a basis for $V^{m,n}$ as defined, although the details of proving that may depend on what you know (the set clearly spans but is not "obviously" linearly independent). In question two, the dimensions add, but the reasoning (where bases from the space can come from) is more important than the answer.

Comment: @green: Is there a precise definition of "vector-valued function space"?  The bracket notation for $S$ that you are using is not standard, and I don't think the term "vector-valued space" has a precise meaning.  I am not trying to be annoying, but it's hard for me (and maybe also for others) to understand what exactly, precisely, $S$ is.